# Как перехватывать и обрабатывать ошибку org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException ... Connection timed out: connect?

Tags: java, proxy, httpclient, timeout

Java приложение отправляет запросы в интернет и получает ответы. Использую Apache HTTP Client. Работа идет через свои HTTP Proxy (3proxy на VPS). Иногда возникает ошибка:

```
сен 24, 2016 5:40:51 PM main_pkg.cycle$JThread1 run
SEVERE: null
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to *PROXY_IP*:*PROXY_PORT* [/PROXY_IP*:*PROXY_PORT*] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:388)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at main_pkg.network.delete_task(network.java:859)
    at main_pkg.task.task_subscribe(task.java:629)
    at main_pkg.task.choise_task_type(task.java:506)
    at main_pkg.cycle$JThread1.run(cycle.java:781)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
    ... 11 more
```

Сам код запроса выглядит так, таймаут задан 61 секунда:

```
        try{

        httpget = new HttpGet("http://myurl.ru/");                
            httpget.setConfig(config);

        response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);    

        } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
        }

        EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
```

Ошибка возникает как я понимаю тогда, когда прокси сервер не отвечает. Ошибка возникает на строке `= httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);` Проблема не в сервере, т.к. это бывает достаточно редко, и любой следующий запрос проходит корректно сразу.

Как ее обрабатывать, что бы при ее возникновении этот же запрос отправлялся заново, и в результате получать корректный ответ? Нужно использовать `try-catch`, но как именно? То что написано сейчас не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш блок `try-catch` перехватывает исключения типа `ConnectTimeoutException`. Угадайте что будет, если возникнет в этом блоке исключение другого типа? Правильно, `try-catch` его пропустит.

```
try{
   ...
} catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO
}
```

Либо вы по очереди перехватываете нужные исключения и решаете что с ними делать

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, значит мне нужно перехватывать HttpHostConnectException ?

Comment: @andrshpa, ну еще в стэке проскакивает `ConnectException` можно и его прихватить